# Loop through looped categories

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I have categories stored in a table and products in another. I have a loop to generate a bootstrap tab html layout.

There's my categories loop PHP code:

```
<ul id="myTabs" role="tablist" class="grid-construct nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
 <?php foreach($this->categories as $i => $category){
    <li role="presentation" class="">
      echo $category->alias;?>
    </li>
    }
 </ul>
```

I have 3 products in each category. Bearing in mind I'm going for a bootstrap tab layout approach, How can i display the through products while looping into each category?

Comment: the opening of your <li> tag lies in the php script and won't be written/echoed. be sure you close the <?php ?> after the foreach definition and open it up before echoing the category-alias. the closing bracket of the foreach loop also needs to be in a <?php } ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to join the product table in the query where you select the categories. Then you can change your code to:

```
<ul id="myTabs" role="tablist" class="grid-construct nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <?php foreach($this->categories as $i => $category): ?>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
      <?php echo $category->alias; ?>
      <?php foreach($category->products as $product): ?>
        <?php echo $product->name; ?>
      <? endforeach; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```